# Matlab: Check all images in a directory for grayscale?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors

I want to check all jpg-images in the current directory if they are grayscale or contain coloured pixels... I tried:

```
figdirectory = pwd;
fullpath = sprintf('%s/*.jpg', figdirectory);
d = dir(fullpath);

% Loop
pages = [];
for i = 1:length(d)
    f = d(i).name;
    fname_input = sprintf('%s/%s', figdirectory, f);

    A = imread(fname_input); 
    B = rgb2gray(A);

    if(A-B == 0)
        hascolor = 0;
    else
        hascolor = 1;
    end
    pages = [pages; hascolor];        
end
```

but this gives me an error about the matrix dimensions of A and B. Why has A a third dimension?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one simple solution based on IMFINFO:

```
%# some test images shipped with the Image Processing Toolbox
fNames = {
    'circles.png'   %# binary
    'shadow.tif'    %# indexed color
    'coins.png'     %# gray
    'peppers.png'   %# RGB
};

isGrayscale = false(size(fNames));
for i=1:numel(fNames)
    imgInfo = imfinfo(fNames{i});
    if strcmp(imgInfo.ColorType,'truecolor')
        isGrayscale(i) = false;
    elseif strcmp(imgInfo.ColorType,'grayscale')
        isGrayscale(i) = true;
    elseif strcmp(imgInfo.ColorType,'indexed')
            %# indexed images colormap (the three channels should be all same)
        isGrayscale(i) = all(all( diff(imgInfo.Colormap,[],2)==0 ,2),1);
    end
end
```

The first part in your case can be:

```
dirName = 'C:\path\to\myimages';
files = dir( fullfile(dirName,'*.jpg') );
fNames = {files.name}';
```

---

#### EDIT:

@Adrian: With regards to the image you posed, as far as the image format saved, it IS a color image. Now the fact that all R/G/B channels are all the same is simply a special case...

Anyway if you want to be able to detect such cases, change the `'truecolor'` part of the above code to:

```
#% ...
if strcmp(imgInfo.ColorType,'truecolor')
    img = imread(fNames{i});
    isGrayscale(i) = isequal(img(:,:,1),img(:,:,2),img(:,:,3));
elseif strcmp(imgInfo.ColorType,'grayscale')
#% ...
```

Comment: Have you tried this on the example image attached to the question? This seems to be a colour scan or picture of a page from a book. Whilst the page is black and white the scanned image actually registered as a truecolor [sic] image.

Comment: @Adrian: see my response above

Comment: just to clarify, the image supplied was added by Col, not myself. Whilst I accept your code is probably more robust in handling different image types, however if all the images in the directory are scanned images from a book and truecolor [sic] then I still prefer my hsv solution as I think it gives cleaner and more readable code, Regards

Comment: First of all, if all images are known to be of one kind, the problem wouldn't exist! Second, you say your code is more readable, but you haven't handled all cases: if image is indexed you have to load the colormap, convert to full RGB, then continue your solution. Finally, my version for the "truecolor" case (load image and check if `R==G==B`) is much faster than converting to HSV then checking if S is all zeros. By definition, saturation is computed from `C=max(R,G,B)-min(R,G,B)` and if `C==0` then `S=0`. Therefore by simply checking if all channels are equal, we avoid a lot of extra work...

Answer (score 4):

To do that:

0) Assuming your input is purely an 'image' and not a 'volume'.

1) [r c d] = size(im);

2) if d is larger than 1, then it is a colored image

3) other wise, it has to be a gray-scale image.

EDITS: 
You can add one more condition to solidly distinguish grey scale img from color ones.  Assuming ur color imgs are of 3 channels,

if d is equal to 3 then check if all 3 channels are equal

im(:,:,1)==im(:,:,2) && im(:,:,1)==im(:,:,3)
Then you have an grayscale image otherwise color img

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code to `A = imread(fname_input); [r c e] = size(A); if(e > 1)   hascolor = 1; else hascolor = 0; end` but it doesn't work: The grayscale-images are also recognized as colored :(

Comment: Is it a colour scan of a page from a book? Hence identified as a colour image.

Comment: @col heather, another definition for a color img is that each pixel in each of the r g b channels is the same. Please see the addition part to my answer

Answer (score 2):

From the manual for imread http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html

> If the file contains a grayscale image, A is an M-by-N array. If the
>   file contains a truecolor image, A is an M-by-N-by-3 array.

So A will have a third dimension for the coloured images.

If you want to test for greyscale then you could convert the image to hsv.

```
B = rgb2hsv(A)
```

from the manual, http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/hsv2rgb.html

> When B(:,2) is 0, the colors are unsaturated (i.e., shades of gray).

In the case of a true colour image like the one posted it will be if unique(B(:,:,2)) is zero, hence

```
A = imread(fname_input);        
B = rgb2hsv(A);

%# if saturation levels are zero then it's a greyscale image
if(unique(B(:,:,2)) == 0)
    hascolor = 0;
else         
    hascolor = 1; 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IMFINFO](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imfinfo.html) for this task, so that you won't have to load the image into memory.

```
figdirectory = pwd;
fullpath = sprintf('%s/*.jpg', figdirectory);
d = dir(fullpath);

nImages = length(d);

%# imageType is a cell array with either 'grayscale', 'truecolor', or 'indexed', 
%# depending on the kind of image you have. 

imageType = cell(nImages,1);

for iImg = 1:nImages
info = imfinfo(d(iImg).name);
imageType{iImg} = info.ColorType;
end

%# isGrayscale is true for grayscale images, false otherwise 
%# (though note that there might be mapped images that map to a grayscale colormap).
isGrayscale = cellfun(@(x)strcmp(x,'grayscale'),imageType);
```

**EDIT**

```
%# the indexed images have to be loaded in order for you to check 
%# for grayscale maps

indexedIdx = find(cellfun(@(x)strcmp(x,'indexed'),imageType));

for iImg = indexedIdx(:)'

   [~,map] = imread(fullfile(figDirectory,d(iImg).name));

   %# It's a grayscale image if rgb map values are all equal
   isGrayscale(iImg) = all(all(bsxfun(@eq,map,map(:,1)),2),1);
end

%# finally, it is possible that the images are *stored* as truecolor
%# but containing, in fact, a grayscale image

truecolorIdx = find(cellfun(@(x)strcmp(x,'truecolor'),imageType));

for iImg = truecolorIdx(:)'

   img = imread(fullfile(figDirectory,d(iImg).name));

   %# It's a grayscale image if rgb map values are all equal
   isGrayscale(iImg) = all(all(all(bsxfun(@eq,img(:,:,1),img),1),2),3);
end
```

Comment: And how to handle this grayscale map? I uploaded a grayscaled picture in the first post which is NOT being handled correctly by your code!

Comment: @Col Heather: You have to load the image to get at the map, then you can check whether it's color or graylevels. See my edit.

Comment: @Col Heather: Also, if the image is *stored* as truecolor, but *contains* only grayvalue information, you need to actually load the image.

Comment: For the example supplied as it is a truecolour image then I don't think imread returns a colour map to process. As updated in my reponse I think it's easier to convert to HSV and check the saturation levels, for greyscale this will be zero.